Retrieving short names of datum accepted in pyproj
I can compile a list of available datum names in pyproj using EPSG codes:
import pyproj
from pyproj.crs import Datum
from pyproj.enums import PJType

auth = "EPSG"
epsg_codes = pyproj.get_codes(auth, PJType.GEODETIC_REFERENCE_FRAME)
datum_names = sorted(Datum.from_authority(auth, code).name for code in epsg_codes)

Which produces a datum name list like:
['AbInvA96_2020 Intermediate Reference Frame', 'Abidjan 1987', 'Accra', 'Aden 1925', ...]

However, pyproj also accepts short datum names. For example, the following calls produce the same result:
d1 = Datum.from_name("World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble")
d2 = Datum.from_name("WGS84")
d3 = Datum.from_name("WGS 84")

Is there a way to retrieve the short names that pyproj accepts for a certain datum?

Since pyproj (see the Documentation) is just a wrapper for PROJ (see the Documentation), the question becomes where does PROJ store the names for geographic datums? The answer comes from the Resource files:

proj.db
A proj installation includes a SQLite database of transformation
information that must be accessible for the library to
work properly. The library will print an error if the database can't
be found.

Coordinate reference systems, datums, transformations, etc... all have formal names and commonly accepted names or aliases.  The projection database stores aliases in a separate table from the formal definition of items, so answering the question requires querying at least two tables.
Using the example geographic datum in the question,
>>> import pyproj
>>> import os
>>> import sqlite3
>>>
>>> projdb_file = os.path.join(pyproj.datadir.get_data_dir(), 'proj.db')
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(projdb_file)
>>>
>>> code = 6326
>>> sql = f"""
...     SELECT auth_name, code, name, 'geodetic_datum' as source
...     FROM geodetic_datum
...     WHERE code = {code}
...
...     UNION ALL
...     SELECT auth_name, code, alt_name as name, 'alias_name' as source
...     FROM alias_name
...     WHERE table_name = 'geodetic_datum'
...     AND code = {code}
...     ORDER BY code, name
... """
>>>
>>> print(*conn.execute(sql).fetchall(), sep="\n")
('EPSG', 6326, 'D_WGS_1984', 'alias_name')
('EPSG', 6326, 'WGS 84', 'alias_name')
('EPSG', 6326, 'WGS84', 'alias_name')
('EPSG', 6326, 'World Geodetic System 1984', 'alias_name')
('EPSG', 6326, 'World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble', 'geodetic_datum')
>>>

If one removes the two SQL lines that contain the code = {code} condition, then a list of 2,300+ names and aliases is returned.
